# Stacked area in Highcharts make my series fading in and fading out

Tags: jquery, html, css, highcharts

I got a rather simple question ( I guess) when displaying a stacked area graph.

Look at this picture:
[image]

What I want is that test1 should end directly at 2024. Now it is "fading out" to the year 2028. The same with test2 and test3: I want to start directly at year 2028 and not allready start at 2024 and "fading in".

Does anyone know if this is possible? I have looked at the API reference but could not find anything relevant.

[DEMO ON JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1qe6drwy/) and code:

```
$(function () {
        var yAxisLabels = [0, 20000, 40000, 60000, 80000, 100000, 120000];
    var xCategories = ['2016', '2020', '2024', '2028', '2032', '2036', '2040'];

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'            
        },
        xAxis: {            
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return xCategories[this.value];
                }
            },
            startOnTick: false,
            endOnTick: false,
            minPadding: 0,
            maxPadding: 0,
        },
        yAxis: {
                startOnTick: true,
            title: {
                enabled: false
            },
            tickPositioner: function() {
                return yAxisLabels;
            },
            labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return "€ " + this.value;
                }
                }
        },
        tooltip: {
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1
            },
            series: {
                fillOpacity: 1
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'test1',
            data: [113864, 113864, 113864, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
        }, {
            name: 'test2',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 87905, 87905, 87905, 87905]            
        }, {
            name: 'test3',
            data: [0, 0, 0, 14211, 14211, 14211, 14211]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `area1` value is zero, yet it is being placed at the top of the stacked areas, hence the odd shape you're seeing. If you place the `area1` data last in the provided array, then the data for `area1` is filled last and appears at the bottom which looks better:

```
series: [{
    name: 'test2',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 87905, 87905, 87905, 87905]
}, {
    name: 'test3',
    data: [0, 0, 0, 14211, 14211, 14211, 14211]
},{
    name: 'test1',
    data: [113864, 113864, 113864, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)'
}]
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1qe6drwy/1/)

Comment: Yep thanks! But this does not solve my problem! The desired lay-out is that test1 directly stops at year 2024 and will not end at 2028. I want to have an area filled with rectangle instead of area ending with a bevelled egde

Comment: I would suggest you use a different style of chart for your data then, as that's not how stacked area charts work. It sounds like you want a stacked column chart instead.

Comment: I think so yeah! Mmm let me have a look at it

Comment: Thank you so much! The last jsfiddle  did the trick! Thank you!